# Codeigniter form_validation doesn't run if I include http://

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I'm having trouble with a form. I've tested it many times and it seems that the problem lies on a string with http:// . Whenever I input www.mywebsite.com it runs but as soon as I input http://mywebsite.com the form doesn't run. Anyone can help??

controller (add.php)

```
public function add_validation(){

    $this->load->library('form_validation');    
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('add', 'Add', 'required|trim');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()){
        echo "The form validation ran";
        //redirect('main/members');
    }else{
        echo "The form validation didn't ran";
        //redirect('main/members');
    }
}
```

view (header.php)

```
            echo form_open('add/add_validation');

            //echo validation_errors();

            $text = array(
                'name' => 'add',
                'id' => 'text',
                'placeholder' => 'http://'
                );

            echo form_input($text);

            $submit = array(
                'name' => 'add_submit',
                'id' => 'submit',
                'value' => '+',
                );

            echo form_submit($submit);

            echo form_close();
```

Comment: Paste your code here.

Comment: Just pasted it. Can you help me? @MRSrinivas

Comment: What is the output you are getting ? That seems fine for me. It tested `http://mywebsite.com` and getting `The form validation ran`.

Comment: I get false if my string has http:// any other string runs. It's weird because on my localhost it works fine using http:// in the string but on the online server I always get false after running it @MRSrinivas